# Trying to convert Javascript recursion to PHP (easy)

Tags: javascript, php, recursion

I have to convert some javascript to PHP for a school project, but there seems to be something I'm missing, because the exact same code is suddenly exiting prematurely.

```
for(var j=0; j<asciiArray.length;j++) {
    passwordFound[location] = String.fromCharCode(asciiArray[j]);

    console.log(passwordFound.join(""));

    if (password === passwordFound.join("")) {
        document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = 'Password: ' + passwordFound.join("");
        return true;
    }
    else if (location < 2) {
        var newlocation = location+1;

        if (characterDecryptFunction(newlocation,asciiArray,passwordFound,password)) return true;
    }

}
```

This is the PHP:

```
function characterDecryptFunction($index, $maxIndex, $asciiArray, $passwordFound, $password)  { 
for ($j=0;$j<count($asciiArray);++$j)
{
    $passwordFound[$index] = chr($asciiArray[$j]);

    echo "<br>" . implode("", $passwordFound);

    if ($password === implode("",$passwordFound)) {
        echo "<br>Password is:" . implode($passwordFound);
        return true;
    }

    elseif ($index < $maxIndex)
    {
        $index = $index+1;

        if (characterDecryptFunction($index,$maxIndex, $asciiArray, $passwordFound, $password) == true) return true;
    }
}
return false;}
```

EDIT:

The javascript is called as such:

```
function decryptFunction() {
var x,y,z,password,asciiArray=[],passwordFound=[];

password="abc";
asciiArray.push(0);
asciiArray.push(32);

for (x=48;x!=58;x++) {
    asciiArray.push(x);
}
for (y=97;y!=123;y++) {
    asciiArray.push(y);
}
for (z=65;z!=91;z++) {
    asciiArray.push(z);
}

characterDecryptFunction(0, asciiArray, passwordFound,password);}
```

And the PHP:

```
function decryptFunction() {
$password = $_POST["password"];
$asciiArray=array();
$passwordFound=array();

for($x=48;$x!=58;$x++) 
{
    array_push($asciiArray, $x);
}

for($x=97;$x!=123;$x++) 
{
    array_push($asciiArray, $x);
}

for($x=65;$x!=91;$x++) 
{
    array_push($asciiArray, $x);
}

for ($x=0;$x<count($asciiArray);$x++) 
{
    echo $asciiArray[$x];
}

echo $password . "<br>";

characterDecryptFunction(0, 2, $asciiArray, $passwordFound, $password); }
```

Comment: When you say prematurely, where do you mean? Also, you'll note that the PHP version has an extra return. I don't know if this is the fault, just a noted difference.

Comment: Whereas the original code goes through all the options, this one suddenly stops at 01Z. It's just a basic cracking algorithm, but it doesnt seem to from 01x to 02x. The extra return is in the original too but I forgot to post it.

Comment: And by `01x` and `02x` what do you mean?

Comment: Well,  the program functions as such: there's an array filled with possible ascii codes that relate to uppercase, lowercase and numbers. Through recursion I try to guess the $password variable. So 000, 001, 002, 003 etc. The original javascript code works, but the PHP code suddenly stops at 01Z, which is the cutoff point when it should go to 020.

Comment: Can you edit the question, add the code so we can see how do you invoke the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems crucial that you do not update $index, just like you do not update *location* in JavaScript. So change the PHP code, introducing *$new_index*:

```
    $new_index = $index+1;

    if (characterDecryptFunction($new_index,$maxIndex, $asciiArray, $passwordFound, $password)) return true;
```

When the algorithm returns from the recursive calls, i.e. when it backtracks to previous characters, it should continue where it left off. For that *$index* must have retained its previous value.

NB: Note that in PHP, just as in JavaScript, you don't need to compare with `true` in the `if` statement when you know the expression is a boolean.